# Nativescript Angular Android App forced light mode not working

Tags: angular, nativescript, cross-platform, nativescript-angular, angular-nativescript

My nativescript android app build using angular in API 29 doesn't get the styles.xml settings from values-v29 folder.

```
<style name="AppThemeBase29" parent="AppThemeBase21">
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
</style>
```

The values-v29 folder only contains the styles.xml file. I have set the forceDarkAllowed to false as shown above. Besides that, I have also set the theme dynamically in main.tns.ts file by:

```
Theme.setMode(Theme.Light);
```

What am I missing? It works on IOS by changing the Info.plist file.

> native script version: 6.5.0 angular version: 8

Answer (score 2):

For Android you might have to implement an application delegate, in your `main.ts` like below

```
import { android, on, launchEvent, ApplicationEventData } from '@nativescript/core/application';

// Typescript will require you to define those types
declare namespace androidx {
 export namespace appcompat {
  export namespace app {
   export const AppCompatDelegate: any;
  }
 }
}

if (android) {
 on(launchEvent, (args: ApplicationEventData) => {
  androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
 });
}
```

Comment: I did try this on main.ts and main.tns.ts files with no difference.